# Keydown event in a certain element of the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, fabricjs

Is it possible to capture the event of a combination of keyboard keys, in a single element of the DOM?
I mean, what I want is that if I have a

```
<div id="k"><input id="text" type="text"></div>
<div id="j"><input id="text" type="text"></div>
```

And I just want to pick up the combination of keys `Ctrl+H` on the div with id "k"

Comment: I know how to work with event keypress in JQuery, i have the code writed, but my problem is that the Ctrl+C

Comment: The problem is that I have defined a custom Ctrl + V for a Canvas, and this event I collect in the Document.

Then, imagine that I execute Ctrl + C in the link bar of the browser to copy the url, but before I did Ctrl + C on my canvas. When I go to Ctrl + V, it executes both my copy function and the windows native

Comment: I understand, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved adding a tabindex 1 to the ".upper-canvas " (yes with blank space) element and then binding the keydown on the ".upper-canvas " with jQuery.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".upper-canvas ").attr('tabindex', 1);
})
$(".upper-canvas ").on("keydown", function(event){
    console.log("Hi");
});
```

[JSFiddle Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/samael205/xpvt214o/131571/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<input id="text" type="text" onkeydown="myFunction1(event)"></div>
<div id="j"><input id="text" type="text"></div>
<script>
function myFunction1(ev) {console.log(ev);}
</script>
```

You can also read at [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a `keydown` (or a `keyup`) event. Then check if the Control key is pressed using `event.ctrlKey` property, and get the currently pressed key using `event.key` property. If both of them are pressed `event.ctrlKey && event.key == 'h'` will be true.

Notice that at the end of the event handler, I am calling [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). It prevents the default action, in this case, browser's shortcut of `Ctrl + H` from being activated.

```js
$("#k").on("keydown", function(event) {
  console.log(event.ctrlKey, event.key);
  
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.key == 'h') {
    alert("Ctrl + H pressed");
  }
  
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="k"><input id="text" type="text"></div>
<div id="j"><input id="text" type="text"></div>
```

Comment: @PedroJose So what happens instead? When I focus on the textbox and press `Ctrl + H` I get an alert in the browser. Does that not happen with your browser?

Comment: Does not happend nothing, i have the same code with a diferent Id, with a console.log inside, and the console does now show on the dev tools.... But does not work on my own code, your example works Fine

Comment: @PedroJose Can you create a working snippet (by editing the question) reproducing that problem? I will see if I can find the problem. Or, if you are comfortable with JS Fiddle or Codepen, that's fine too.

Comment: Ok, I created the fiddle as I have it and it does not work XD [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samael205/xpvt214o/117806/)

Comment: @PedroJose I wonder if the problem is because the canvas element doesn't allow a keypress event. You could try listening to the event on document element, and then if it is actually `Ctrl + V` you can execute logic specific to that. So the event binding would be: `$(document).on("keydown", function...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168899/discussion-between-pedro-jose-and-nisarg).