# Handeling keydown events only in top layer of html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working on a webapplication, where I have an underlying html file with some JS functionality, that I can't interfer with.
Via JS, I create a layer above that page with `z-index: 1000;` in my css.
Now I need some inputs, but my keydown events must not interact with the "page" underneath.

My idea was to work with something like:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

This should, in my understanding, stop the event from triggering. But it also disables the input in my overlay.

Is there a possibility to only accept key inputs in a `<textarea>` but not trigger keydown events in the underlying page?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Code:

.html

standard html with `<head>` and `<body>`, that I don't want to interact with, because it's an 10 year old software running in the manufacturing in my company.

.js

```
function createModal() {
  return '<div class="modal" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modalContainer">
     <div class="modalHeader">Störmeldungen<span id="closeModal" class="btn" style="float: right">X</span></div>
     <div class="modalBody"><div class="btn" id="btnHistory">Verlauf anzeigen</div><div class="btn btnNewMessage">Neue Meldung absetzen</div></div></div></div>
</div>';
}
```

```
function inputMessage() {
  return (
    '<div id="customMessage">
         <div id="textInput"><label for="description" id="inputLabel">Um was für ein Problem handelt es sich?</label><br><textarea id="description" placeholder="Bitte beschreiben Sie den Fehler"></textarea></div>' +
        '<div class="checkBox"><label for="localSupport">Ich benötige Hilfe vor Ort</label><input type="checkbox" id="localSupport"></div>' +
        '<div class="checkBox"><label for="noKeyboard">Ich verfüge nicht über eine Tastatur</label><input type="checkbox" id="noKeyboard"></div>' +
        '<div class="btn" id="sendMessage">Störmeldung absetzen</div>
    </div>'
  );
}
```

```
$("body").prepend(createModal());
$(".modalContainer").append(createMessage());
$(".secondModal .modalBody").append(inputMessage());
```

.css

```
.modal {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;

.modal .modalContainer {
  margin: 5% auto;
  width: 75%;
  height: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
}
```

Comment: If the intent behind this is to restrict what clients can do in the browser, you should be mindful of the fact that it is trivial for even an inexperienced user to figure out how to disable or modify JS in their client

Comment: Please add the HTML, CSS and JS you use to create the overlay in to the question

Comment: Added parts of the code. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work?
By linking the keydown on the hidden html.

```
$( "#idForUnderlyingHtml" ).keydown(function( event ) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: I now tried, with no positive result:

`$(document).on("keydown", "#idOfUnderlyingHtml", function (e) {
  if ($(".modal").is(":visible")) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});`

Comment: @fatum_insect maby this can help you out https://stackoverflow.com/q/49811021/12564616